# exact solution to lotka-volterra equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system

I am looking for exact or perturbative solution realistic lotka-volterra (the one with logistic term in one of the equations) equations in population dynamics.

Any reference where they have done it will be useful.

Comment: Do you need $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ or $y(x)$ would be nice?

Comment: I need $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.

Comment: You can easily find solution in a neighbourhood of equilibrium point (it's sine-cosine), but as far as I know, solution in general is numerical.

Comment: Linear analysis is not something that i am looking for. Any perturbation theory that you can suggest?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lotka-VolterraEquations.html , https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka_Volterra_equation

Comment: yeah but couldnt find any paper or reference where $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ is calculated. They all seem to do some sort of qualitative analysis of this system.

Answer (score 6):

We cannot find exact solution in a closed form, but I hope it will be useful.

So, we have the system
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
\dot x &= \alpha x - \beta xy=x(\alpha - \beta y),\\
\dot y &= -\gamma y + \delta xy = y(-\gamma + \delta x)
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
From first equation
$$
\frac{\dot x}{x} = \alpha - \beta y\Longrightarrow \beta y = \alpha - \frac{\dot x}{x}
$$
Let's substitute it into second:
$$
\beta\dot y = \beta y(-\gamma + \delta x)
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\dot x}{x} + \Big(\alpha - \frac{\dot x}{x}\Big)(-\gamma + \delta x) = 0
$$
$$
\frac{x\ddot x - \dot x^2}{x^2} + \Big(\alpha - \frac{\dot x}{x}\Big)(-\gamma + \delta x) = 0
$$
$$
{x\ddot x - \dot x^2} + (\alpha x^2 - x\dot x)(\delta x-\gamma) = 0
$$
Let $\dot x = p$; then $\ddot x = p\frac{dp}{dx}$,
$$
pxp'-p^2 + (\alpha x^2 - xp)(\delta x-\gamma) = 0
$$
Divide by $x^2$:
$$
\frac{p}{x}p'-\frac{p^2}{x^2} + \Big(\alpha - \frac{p}{x}\Big)(\delta x-\gamma) = 0
$$
Let $p=xq$:
$$
q(q + xq') - q^2 + (\alpha - q)(\delta x - \gamma) = 0
$$
$$
xq\frac{dq}{dx} + (\alpha - q)(\delta x - \gamma) = 0
$$
$$
\frac{qdq}{\alpha - q} + \Big(\delta - \frac{\gamma}{x}\Big)dx = 0
$$
$$
-q-\alpha\ln|q-\alpha|+\delta x-\gamma\ln x = C
$$
But $q=p/x=\dot x/x=\alpha - \beta y$ ($q\le\alpha$ always) and $q_0 = \alpha - \beta y_0$
$$
-q_0-\alpha\ln|q_0-\alpha|+\delta x_0-\gamma\ln x_0 = C
$$
$$
C = -q_0-\alpha\ln(\beta y_0)+\delta x_0-\gamma\ln x_0
$$
So,
$$
-q-\alpha\ln(\alpha-q)+\delta x-\gamma\ln x = C
$$
We may solve this equation using [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):
$$
q=\alpha\left[1 + W\left(-\frac1\alpha \exp\left(-\frac1\alpha(\alpha - \delta x + \gamma\ln x + C)\right)\right)\right].
$$
But $q = \dot x/x$ and
$$
\int\frac{dx/x}{1 + W\left(-\frac1\alpha \exp\left(-\frac1\alpha(\alpha - \delta x + \gamma\ln x + C)\right)\right)} = \int\alpha dt
$$
I'm sure that there is no closed form for integral in LHS.

Comment: Interestingly, the whole circuit you use to get $$-q-\alpha\ln(\alpha-q)+\delta x-\gamma\ln x = C$$ with $\alpha-q=\beta y$, can be replaced by the remark that the original system implies $$\frac{\dot x}x(\delta x-\gamma)=(\delta x-\gamma)(\alpha-\beta y)=\frac{\dot y}y(\alpha-\beta y)$$ hence, since both sides are exact differentials, one gets directly $$\delta x-\gamma\ln x=\alpha\ln y-\beta y+C$$

Comment: @Did, yes, indeed. Thank you for the observation. I just used the most straightforward way (for me)

Comment: Indeed, the parenthesis appealing to subjectivity in your comment seems necessary to explain the qualification that precedes it...