# How to find the $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ functions in the Lotka Volterra Equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I'm doing this math project involving the [Lotka-Volterra equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka-Volterra_equations). My goal was to be able to graph both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ on the same axis against time. 
So far, I was able to find the combined equation of *x'* and *y'* using partial differentiation. I called it $E(x,y)$. Substituting my known constants, we have $$E(x,y)=2\ln(y)+4\ln(x)-y-x.$$ However, I have come to a standstill in my progress, as I now cannot separate *x* and *y* to find $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, which are defined as $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$. All online sources I have consulted do not explain how they get the graph I'm looking for.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Well, do you need exact graphs, or approximate numerics, or qualitative picture?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exact solution to lotka-volterra equations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367652/exact-solution-to-lotka-volterra-equations)

Comment: I need to be able to graph both functions x(t) and y(t) against time.